# Download and save png picture to local storage Windows Phone background agent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm downloading a picture from internet and saving it to the local storage in a backgroundAgent. With ".jpg" it works fine using [SaveJPeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
But, if I ddownload a ".png" or ".wdp" file I don't know how to save it in the correct format. The namespace "System.Windows.Media.Imaging" does not provide any method to save in another format. 
EDIT: I need the image to set it as lockscreen background.

Comment: Have you looked into isolated storage? I built a free library called EZ_Iso that helps you do operations like your explanation with a single line of code. Version 4.0, Documentation and source code can all be found here http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Comment: I don't understand how this dll can help with my problem... I can not find a way to store a ".png", ".wdp" file to set it as lockscreen background.

Comment: You're trying to save it to the device right? That's what Isolated storage is for.

Comment: I know, but I need to save it in the correct format to set it as lockscreen background later.

Comment: Anyway, I'll give a try to your library, thanks.

Comment: Then I would read how isolated storage works and look at the source I provided. The DLL wont help you but the source is exactly what you need with a little modification

Answer (score 0):

Try this:- these files are binary files so for storing them to isolated storage use this.

check also the stream position property it should be set to Zero(0).

```
public static async Task SaveToIsolatedStorage(Stream fs, string fileName)
    {
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var output = storage.CreateFile(fileName))
            {
                await fs.CopyToAsync(output);
            }
        }
    }
```

For exploring IsolatedStorage use [**IsoStoreSpy**](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/releases).

Comment: If I do a "CopyToAsync(stream)" the image file will be corrupted. I need a way to store the file in the correct format. Like I said, the problem is not related to save the file, is related to the way the image is stored.